# Mobile application HTML5 super blurry map images

Tags: tizen, here-api, tizen-web-app

I am developing a webapp for Tizen (aka Meego 2.0) using MH5 and the map images are super blurry.

I am using the very basic sample that shows a map with a search bar, without touching the code. It seems like the image resolution is 4 times lower than it should be I can't even read the text. All UI elements are fine though.

I tried to switch the HW acceleration off, but it's the same.
What else can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the pixel density by invoking the `normal.day.mobile` or `normal.day.hires` schema as shown. The pixels per inch should increase from 72ppi to 250ppi or 320ppi.

```
 page = new nokia.mh5.ui.Page({
                children: ["map"],
                layout: {
                    type: nokia.mh5.ui.RowLayout
                },
                visible: true,
                controls: {
                    control: nokia.mh5.ui.Container,
                    children: [ "show" ],
                    layout: {
                        type: nokia.mh5.ui.ColumnLayout
                    }

                },

                map: {
                    control: nokia.mh5.components.Map,
                    center: {
                        longitude: 13.405,
                        latitude: 52.515
                    },
                    //enable either box or zoom
                    zoom: 13,
                    schema: "normal.day.mobile"
                }
            });
```